# Unable to read txt file by line

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I tried to read a txt file (with texts inside) in every lines .Then I will process the lines later .

Here is my work.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Fypio {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String fileName = "e://input.txt";

        //read file into stream, try-with-resources
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            stream.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

However, I get the following error. I am definitely sure that the directory is correct though.

Error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
>   at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:574)
>   at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
>   at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
>   at fypio.Fypio.main(Fypio.java:21)
> Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
>   at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
>   at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:571)
>   ... 4 more
> ```

## #Or any sample codes can be provided to read txt file by line ?

## Update my txt files should be encoded with `ANSI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MalformedInputException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/MalformedInputException.html) means your text file is not in the [charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (encoding) you requested.

Although your code does not explicitly specify a charset, the [Files.lines method always uses UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-):

> Read all lines from a file as a `Stream`. Bytes from the file are decoded into characters using the `UTF-8 charset`.

Since your text file is not a UTF-8 text file, you’ll need to [specify its charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) in your code.  If you aren’t sure, the file probably uses the system’s default charset:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
```

**Update:**

You have stated in a comment that your text file is “ANSI,” which is the (technically incorrect) name Windows uses for its one-byte charsets.  On a US version of Windows, you’d probably want to use:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.forName("windows-1252"))) {
```

Comment: my txt should be encoded with `ANSI` . But your code is not working

Comment: Are you getting the same exception?

Comment: YES ............

Comment: Answer updated.  Try using an explicit charset corresponding to what Windows calls “ANSI.”